# How to create a backup of a MySQL table where the original table has a "set" data type for one of the columns?

Tags: mysql

I need to create a table backup in MySQL before updating some data in the original table.  The server is running MySQL 5.6. The plan is to create a new blank table and select the data from the original table using an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`

I used `SHOW CREATE TABLE Organization;` to get the statement necessary to create the new blank `Organization_backup` table. Below is a sample table structure from the original table.

```
MySQL [db]> describe Organization;
+------------------+-------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field            | Type                                            | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------+-------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ID               | char(6)                                         | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Plans            | set('plan1','plan2','plan3')                    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| CreatedTS        | datetime                                        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------------+-------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

My insert statement is pretty simple:

```
INSERT INTO Organization_backup (ID, Plans, CreatedTS)
SELECT ID, Plans, CreatedTS FROM Organization;
```

However, when I then compare the tables for mismatched data, I can see that the Plans value is not matched. Particularly, an organization can be part of more than 1 plan and I believe the resulting subset of data with comma-separated values is causing an issue when the data is being inserted into the backup table.

Example `SELECT ID,Plans,CreatedTS FROM Organization where ID = 'ORG1';`

**RESULT:**

```
+---------+----------------------+---------------------+
|    ID   |       Plans          | CreatedTS           |
+---------+----------------------+---------------------+
|  ORG1   |  plan1,plan2,plan3   | 2017-05-05 14:26:25 |
+---------+----------------------+---------------------+
```

Compared to Example `SELECT ID,Plans,CreatedTS FROM Organization_backup where ID = 'ORG1';`

**RESULT:**

```
+---------+----------------------+---------------------+
|    ID   |         Plans        | CreatedTS           |
+---------+----------------------+---------------------+
|  ORG1   |     plan2,plan3      | 2017-05-05 14:26:25 |
+---------+----------------------+---------------------+
```

I can't figure out why the first plan in the set isn't being inserted properly.

**EDIT1:**
For those asking, yes the two tables are identical besides the name.

```
MySQL [db]> describe Organization_backup;
+------------------+-------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field            | Type                                            | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------+-------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ID               | char(6)                                         | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Plans            | set('plan1','plan2','plan3')                    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| CreatedTS        | datetime                                        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------------+-------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: please print here `describe Organization_backup ;`

Comment: Backup as `SELECT ... , Plans + 0, ...`. You'll receive not textual representation but its INT value. This numeric value may be used in INSERT without transformations, as-is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE Organization_backup SELECT * FROM Organization;
```

Comment: So... this is so simple compared to what I was trying to do. And you replied so fast.  Thanks for the help! This worked flawlessly for my needs.

Comment: I actually don't know why your way didn't work but I use this combined `CREATE TABLE .. SELECT` syntax for ad-hoc backups, and I guessed that at the very least it might make your other backups more convenient :)